# Evaluating an HTML/JS string in Java

Tags: java, javascript, html

I have a Java string containing HTML/JS/CSS code like this (very simple example):

```
<div>Welcome</div>
<style type="text/css">
.title{
color:red
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
var i=0;
for (i=0;i < 5;i++){
document.writeln("<div class='title'>" + i + "</div>");
}
</script>
```

I receive that string on the Java side.

What I want is to "render" that string as it will be displayed on the browser.

So, I want to obtain the following result on my Java side :

```
Welcome
0
1
2
3
4
```

Is there a method like this ?

```
String renderedHTMLJS = therenderingmethod(htmljsString);
```

How can I do this ?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by `Java to evaluate that string` ? What op you want?

Comment: You can try and use rhino (I use it for the regex engine), but it won't affect `document` (I think)

Comment: I mean to generate the output on the Java side. I don't know, maybe a function like this : if (generate(htmljsString).isEmpty){ System.out.println("the htmljsString won't generate something on the client browser");}

Comment: @RanRag I edited the post for more clarity.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `Rhino` from Mozilla and using its integration libraries or by using the JDK 1.6 `ScriptEngine` facility.

For `ScriptEngine` Example take a look here- http://metoojava.wordpress.com/2010/06/20/execute-javascript-from-java/

Comment: AFAIK, ScriptEngine is for scripting only. It cannot "renders" the HTML part.

Comment: Should be fine, but a document object will have to injected into the context, doesn't have to be a DOM, just a mock object to capture data passed to writeln (and any other methods).

Comment: @vickirk In my example (ex : "<div>Welcome</div>" at the very top), some parts of the DOM are "static". Can ScriptEngine renders them ?

Comment: I agree with vickirk a DOM or any other object has to be introduced to pass the data to the methods.

Comment: @RanRag How do you inject static DOM to a JavaScript Engine ? it's like your are writing the following code : `<script type="text/javascript"><b>Welcome</b></script>` which is totally wrong. May be am I missing something? can you show us some code ?

Comment: No, it can't.  But as you say that is static so you don't have to.  Extract the javascript snippets out, execute them and replace the nodes in the original DOM with the output.   Note, I doubt this will scale up to complex scripts.

Comment: Sorry, I can't accept your answer since it doesn't resolve the problem.